Who said, "I want to live long enough to see what becomes of Napoleon"?
My memory is that someone in very poor health (a literary figure? or an exile?) was asked by a visitor (with more curiosity than tact, I imagine) how he was managing to keep hanging on, and that he answered in roughly those words.
But who?

I've always thought it was Talleyrand, but can't find any historical evidence to rely on at the moment. Portrait of Talleyrand by quotes. This type of punchline was typically the one of a man who admired then was disappointed, as Talleyrand was with Napoleon.

I had a quick look here https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Napoleon#Quotes_about_Napoleon and couldn't see it, but I may have missed it

I suppose Talleyrand is possible ... but given that he outlived Napoleon by so many years, Ithink less likely?
Perhaps if he said it much earlier in their careers, simply as a clever remark ...but my memory really was of someone just hanging on.

@Barnaby: he faced so many important people (many of whom died shortly before/after 1821) that it might be useful to see if any of these names (in "commanders and leaders") rings a bell? Especially if these words might have been said between 1815 and 1821?

It was Thomas Jefferson. From a letter to John Adams dated July 5, 1814:

I learned with great regret the serious illness mentioned in your
letter: and I hope mr Rives will be able to tell me you are entirely
restored. but our machines have now been running for 70. or 80. years,
and we must expect that, worn as they are, here a pivot, there a
wheel, now a pinion, next a spring, will be giving way: and however we
may tinker them up for awhile, all will at length surcease motion. our
watches, with works of brass and steel, wear out within that period.
shall you and I last to see the course of the seven-fold wonders of
the times will take? the Attila of the age dethroned, the ruthless
destroyer of 10. millions of the human race, whose thirst for blood
appeared unquenchable, the great oppressor of the rights & liberties
of the world, shut up within the circuit of a little island of the
Mediterranean ... etc


Obviously my memory of the circumstances was very poor! Possibly I read a paraphrased version? And I suppose a great many people were wondering, "What will become of Napoleon?".
